# DirectionsService.Route - try to acces lat, lng not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From a DestinationsService.Route response I would like to access the `lat` and `lng` values like the following:

```js
var latitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lat;
var longitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lng;
console.log("var ["+latitude0+","+longitude0+"]");
```

Viewing the DestinationsService.Route with the Firefox debugger the json response looks like the following:

```js
"routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {...}
     },
     "copyrights" : "Map data ©2015 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {...},
           "duration" : {...},
           "end_address" : "something",
           "end_location" : {...},
           "start_address" : "another thing",
           "start_location" : {...},
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {...},
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "2 mins",
                    "value" : 104
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 14.64548629999999,
                    "lng" : 21.0152624
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "...",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "..."
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 14.64537809999999,
                    "lng" : 17.9754639
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
```

I can access all other fields and values within the `steps[0]`, e.g.

```js
routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].travel_mode
```

which gives me "DRIVING" or

```js
routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].duration.text
```

which gives me "2 mins".

But when accessing as explained in the beginning lat and lng of `start_location` or `end_location` it gives me (which is the console print-out):

```js
var [function (){"use strict"; return a},function (){"use strict";return b}]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: same problem happened to me, did google change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) object has lat/lng methods, you need to call them to get the appropriate value.  Instead of:

```
var latitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lat;
var longitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lng;
```

Do:

```
var latitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lat();
var longitude0 = routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].start_location.lng();
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sbnmj5ay/1/)